# What are zigzag theories, and why are they called that?

Tags: set-theory

I've encountered the term *zigzag theory* while randomly clicking my way through the internet. It is given [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2011035). I haven't been able to find a clear explanation of what constitutes a zigzag theory. [Here](http://richardhartersworld.com/cri/2006/zigzag.html), it is said that they have to do with non-Cantorian sets, which, as I understand, are sets that fail to satisfy Cantor's theorem. The article also says that New Foundations is a zigzag theory, but I don't see that it says why exactly that is so. I have gone through the Wikipedia article on New Foundations, and there's nothing about zigzags in it.

So what makes a zigzag theory? And what's zigzagging about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is taken from (it is probably important to note the year of the article):

> B. Russell, *On some difficulties in the theory of transfinite numbers and order types*, Proc. London Math. Soc. Ser.II, Vol.4 (1907), No.1, pp.29-53, [journal link](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-4/1/29.full.pdf+html).

We first take a definition from the article.

> A *propositional function of $x$* is any expression $\phi ! x$ whose value, for every
>   value of $x$, is a proposition; such is "$x$ is a man" or "$\sin x = 1$."

Now onto one of the theories discussed in the paper.

> In the zigzag theory, we
>   start from the suggestion that propositional functions determine classes
>   when they are fairly simple, and only fail to do so when they are complicated
>   and recondite.  If this is the case, it cannot be bigness that makes
>   a class go wrong; for such propositional functions as "$x$ is not a man"
>   have an exemplary simplicity, and are yet satisfied by all but a finite
>   number of entites.  In this theory, as well as in the theory of limitation
>   of size, we define a *predicative* propositional function as one which determines
>   a class (or a relation, if it contains two variables); thus in the
>   zigzag theory the negation of a predicative function is always predicative.
>   In other words, given any class $u$, all the terms which are not members of
>   $u$ form a class which may be called the class not-$u$.
>
> If now $\phi ! x$ is a non-predicative function, it follows that, given any
>   class $u$, there must either be members of $u$ for which $\phi ! x$ is false, or
>   members of not-$u$ for which $\phi ! x$ is true.  (For, if not, $\phi ! x$ would be true
>   when, and only when, $x$ is a member of $u$; so that $\phi ! x$ would be predicative.)
>   It thus appears that $\phi ! x$ fails to be predicative just as much by
>   the terms it does not include as by the terms it does.  Again, given
>   any class $u$, the property $\phi ! x$ belongs either to some some, but not all, of
>   the members of $u$ or to some, but not all, of the members of 
>   not-$u$.  This is the zigzag property which gives its name to the theory 
>   we are considering.

Russell goes on to explain a bit more.

> The zigzag theory, in some form or other, is that assumed in the
>   definitions of cardinal and ordinal numbers as classes of classes (if
>   numbers are supposed to be entities). For all these classes of classes, if
>   they are legitimate, must contain as many members as there are entities
>   altogether; hence, if bigness makes classes go wrong, as we suppose in
>   the "limitation of size" theory, cardinals and ordinals so defined will
>   be illegitimate classes.

Comment: Historically Russell was not at all wrong in that last quote. Ordinals and cardinals considered as equivalence classes are not sets. It was only some 15-20 years later that von Neumann proposed to define ordinals as particular sets; and roughly half a century before Scott proposed how to define cardinals as sets without the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 4):

As a footnote to Arthur Fischer, here's an additional quote from Michael Potter's *Set Theory and its Philosophy*:

> In 1906, Russell canvassed three forms a solution to the paradoxes might take:
>   the no-class theory, limitation of size, and the zigzag theory. It is striking that a century later all of the theories that have been studied in any detail are recognizably descendants of one or other of these. Russell’s no-class theory became the theory of types, and the idea that the iterative conception is interpretable as a cumulative version of the theory of types was explained with great clarity by Gödel in a lecture he gave in 1933, ... although the view that it is an independently motivated notion rather than a device to make the theory more susceptible to metamathematical investigation is hard to find in print before Gödel 1947. The doctrine of limitation of size ... has received rather
>   less philosophical attention, but the cumulatively detailed analysis in Hallett
>   1984 can be recommended. **The principal modern descendants of Russell’s
>   zigzag theory -- the idea that a property is collectivizing provided that its syntactic expression is not too complex -- are Quine’s two theories NF and ML.**
>   Research into their properties has always been a minority sport: for the current
>   state of knowledge consult Forster 1995. What remains elusive is a proof
>   of the consistency of NF relative to ZF or any of its common strengthenings.